# Reduce Toolbar Icon Padding(Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way that the spacing between two icons on the Nav Bar can be reduced in Xamarin.Forms?

See the image below for the problem:

[Icons with too much spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn04p.png)

This distance is fine for 2 icons, but when using 3, it takes up half of the Nav Bar - any way this can be reduced?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using bar buttons?? check out the size of image you are using as it increases the size of bar button.

Comment: The image is 24x24 and it takes up all that horizontal space.
I'm using Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItems.

Comment: Please add a Print Screen to watch better your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it two ways, by creating a NavigationRenderer, or a PageRenderer. You have to recreate UIButtons to replace each toolbar item, and take the delegate an image from the Xamarin.Forms item. When you set the CGREct to the UIButton, here is where you can adjust the height and width properties.

Here is my implementation using a PageRenderer.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]
public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
     protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);
     }

     public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
     {
         base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

         var navigationItem = this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

         foreach (var rightItem in navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems)
         {
             var button = new UIButton(new CGRect(0, 0, 50, 50));
             button.SetImage(rightItem.Image, UIControlState.Normal);

             FieldInfo fi = rightItem.GetType().GetField("clicked", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
             Delegate del = (Delegate)fi.GetValue(rightItem);
             button.TouchUpInside += (EventHandler)del;

             rightItem.CustomView = button;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you dynamically change the toolbar items in your Xamarin.Forms page, it will override the render changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the fade in/out effect when the button is clicked?

Comment: This works except that the tint colour does not apply as it does without the renderer.

Comment: With this, you'll get the tint color for the icons:

`var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);`

Comment: To add to this, my images were stretched with this, so I added `button.ImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to get the effect you want, check my sample code:

```
public class MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MainViewController ()
    {
        this.View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        UIImage image1 = UIImage.FromFile ("test1.png");
        UIImage image2 = UIImage.FromFile ("test2.png");

        //The regular way to set right bar items
//      UIBarButtonItem barBtn1 = new UIBarButtonItem (image1, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, null);
//      UIBarButtonItem barBtn2 = new UIBarButtonItem (image2, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, null);
//      this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems (new UIBarButtonItem[]{ barBtn1, barBtn2 }, true);

        //Use CustomView with two UIButton as a right bar item
        int btnLength = 35;

        UIButton btn1 = new UIButton ();
        btn1.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, btnLength, btnLength);
        btn1.SetImage (image1, UIControlState.Normal);
        btn1.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("btn1 clicked.");
        };

        UIButton btn2 = new UIButton ();
        btn2.Frame = new CGRect (10+btnLength, 0, btnLength, btnLength);
        btn2.SetImage (image2, UIControlState.Normal);
        btn2.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("btn2 clicked.");
        };

        UIView toolbar = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 0, 10+2*btnLength, btnLength));
        toolbar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        toolbar.AddSubview (btn1);
        toolbar.AddSubview (btn2);

        this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem (new UIBarButtonItem (toolbar),true);
    }
}
```

And this is the screenshot for 2 different way, the regular style:

[image]

And the CustomView style:

[image]

If you still have some problems, just leave it here, I'll check it latter.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This solution doesn't fit my problem - I am using 'Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem's. Is there no way to just reduce the spacing?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use same theory like my code in Xamarin.Forms, but for sure there is no way to just reduce the spacing weather in Native or Xamarin.iOS, so I don't think you can find a way just working for Xamarin.Forms. By the way, if you just want get the answer for Xamarin.Forms, you should pay more attention about the key word of your description, using the key word "Xamarin.Forms" not "Xamarin iOS".